# Error in cholesky decompostion of large matrix in R

Tags: r

I am trying to decompose a large covariance matrix as part of a portfolio optimisation in R, but it doesn't seem to work for matrices with more than ~100 variables. Here is an example with some random data:

```
set.seed(123)
a <- NULL

for(i in 1:300) {
  a <- cbind(a, rnorm(100))
}

chol(cov(a))

Error in chol.default(cov(a)) : 
  the leading minor of order 101 is not positive definite
```

but if I reduce the sample it works fine:

```
b <- NULL

for(i in 1:100) {
  b <- cbind(b, rnorm(100)) 
}

chol(cov(b))
```

I've tried it a few times, and the error seems to occur for covariance matrices with more than 100 to 105 variables. Does anyone know the source of this problem?

EDIT 2: This works:

```
set.seed(123)
c <- NULL

for(i in 1:300) {
  c <- cbind(c, rnorm(300))
}

chol(cov(c))
```

But this does not:

```
d <- NULL

for(i in 1:301) {
  d <- cbind(d, rnorm(300))
}

chol(cov(d))

Error in chol.default(cov(d)) : 
  the leading minor of order 300 is not positive definite
```

So the number of variables may not exceed the number of observations?

Comment: I think this question has been answered comprehensively over here... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55925/the-leading-minor-of-order-1-is-not-positive-definite-error-using-2l-norm-in-m

Comment: It is the same error, but I believe the cause might be different. The answer to that question states that "The problem occurs because you have overfitted your model (too many parameters, variables), some variables are highly colinear or you have cases that have missings on all variables...", but that doesn't seem to apply in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have a 100 observations, your covariance matrix will have rank at most 100. This is the reason that the cholesky factorization is failing.

Comment: So the number of variables may not exceed the number of observations?

Comment: Exactly. The help page for `chol` says: "Compute the Choleski factorization of a real symmetric positive-definite square matrix". If your number of variables exceeds the number of observations your matrix is no longer positive definite.